# Configuring AutoMapper 4.2 with built in IoC in ASP.NET Core 1.0 MVC6

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to figure out the proper way to configure AutoMapper in my application's Startup.cs file and then use it throughout my application.

I am trying to use [this documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Migrating-from-static-API) which somewhat explains how to still give AutoMapper a static feel without the old static API. The example uses StructureMap.

I would like to know how I can do something similar, but in a Core 1.0 app using the built in services container.

I am assuming that in the Configure function I would configure AutoMapper and then in the ConfigureServices function I would add it as a transient.

I am assuming in the end the cleanest and most proper way to do this is using dependency injection. Here is my current attempt but it is not working:

**Startup.cs**

```
public IMapper Mapper { get; set; }
private MapperConfiguration MapperConfiguration { get; set; }
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddTransient<IMapper, Mapper>();
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    MapperConfiguration MapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Product, ProductViewModel>().ReverseMap();
    });

    Mapper = MapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
}
```

**In my controller:**

```
private IMapper _mapper { get; set; }
// Constructor
public ProductsController(IMapper mapper)
{
    _mapper = mapper;
}

public IActionResult Create(ProductViewModel vm)
{
    Product product = _mapper.Map<ProductViewModel, Product>(vm);
}
```

It just isn't working at all... I must be missing some step or doing something wrong.

Comment: I don't have the complete answer for this (struggling with it myself!), but in your AddTransient, the second generic param is the *type* of Mapper rather than the instance of Mapper that you created with CreateMapper.  I'm guessing it's going to be something along the lines of the services.AddInstance instead.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This answer suits the MVC 6 approach a little more around the Controller layer:

I migrated from AutoMapper 4.1.1 to 4.2.0, had a few issues figuring out the intricacies but got there in the end.

First I separated the AutoMapper Profile build into a new class (see below) to save clogging up the Startup class.

```
using AutoMapper;
using YourModels;
using YourViewModels;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class AutoMapperProfileConfiguration : Profile
    {
        protected override void Configure()
        {
            CreateMap<Application, ApplicationViewModel>();
            CreateMap<ApplicationViewModel, Application>();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I made the following amendments to the Startup class.

I added private member variable of type MapperConfiguration.

```
private MapperConfiguration _mapperConfiguration { get; set; }
```

In the Startup constructor I added the following code to instantiate my new AutoMapper Profile.

```
_mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddProfile(new AutoMapperProfileConfiguration());
});
```

In `ConfigureServices()` I dropped my new AutoMapper Profile into a Singleton.

```
services.AddSingleton<IMapper>(sp => _mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper());
```

It was then just a simple operation to inject it the relevant controllers.

```
using AutoMapper;
using ...

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class ApplicationsController : BaseController
    {
        [FromServices]
        private IMapper _mapper { get; set; }

        [FromServices]
        private IApplicationRepository _applicationRepository { get; set; }

        public ApplicationsController(
            IMapper mapper,
            IApplicationRepository applicationRepository)
        {
            _mapper = mapper;
            _applicationRepository = applicationRepository;
        }

        // GET: Applications
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<Application> applications = await _applicationRepository.GetForIdAsync(...);

            if (applications == null)
                return HttpNotFound();

            List<ApplicationViewModel> viewModel = _mapper.Map<List<ApplicationViewModel>>(applications);

            return View(viewModel);
        }

        ...
}
```

Thanks to Rexebin over at https://pintoservice.wordpress.com/2016/01/31/dependency-injection-for-automapper-4-2-in-asp-net-vnext-mvc-project/ for his post which help enourmously.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the extension package from the automapper creator.

You can pass in a configuration, specify assemblies to scan or pass nothing and let it scan assemblies from the DependencyContext.

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection

https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //configure DI
    services.AddTransient<IFoo, Foo>();

    //Add automapper - scans for Profiles
    services.AddAutoMapper();
    //or specify
    services.AddAutoMapper(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile<ViewModelProfile>();
        ...
    });
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

In your ConfigurationServices you can new up an instance of MapperConfiguration and then create your maps and add them.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{     
    MapperConfiguration configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
       cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile.Profile1>();
       cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile.Profile2>();
    });

    services.AddInstance(typeof (IMapper), configuration.CreateMapper());
}
```

Then you just inject the IMapper in your constructor and map

```
public class Handler
{
      private readonly ProfileContext _db;
      private readonly IMapper _mapper;

      public Handler(ProfileContext db, IMapper mapper)
      {
          _db = db;
          _mapper = mapper;
      }

      public void Handle(Profile1 request)
      {

          ProfileModel profile = _mapper.Map<Profile1, ProfileModel>(request);

          _db.Profiles.Add(profile);

          try
          {
              db.SaveChanges();
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {

              throw;
          }

          return profile;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The posted answer is a great solution, but I figured I would let you guys know how I am currently doing it with Core 1.0 and AutoMapper v5.1.1. I feel like it is a very nice approach and easy to understand.

In Startup.cs at the top of the Configure method simply write the following code to initialize your mappings:

```
Mapper.Initialize(config =>
{
     config.CreateMap<ProductViewModel, Product>().ReverseMap();
     config.CreateMap<CustomerViewModel, Customer>().ReverseMap();
});
```

Then in your controller or any other part of your code where you need to map:

```
Mapper.Map<Product>(productViewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just experimenting with moving a Web API over from .net 4.5 to .net core and needed this. You were very close, as @DavidGouge suggested you need to register the mapper instance you have created in the IOC. So the AutoMapper configuration needs to be done in ConfigureServices. (Have included in line here, but in my project it calls a method in an AutoMapperConfiguration class, so Startup stays as clean as possible, same with the IOC registrations). The IMapper will then be correctly populated in your controller.

**Startup.cs becomes**

```
   public IMapper Mapper { get; set; }
   private MapperConfiguration MapperConfiguration { get; set; }
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
        MapperConfiguration MapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Product, ProductViewModel>().ReverseMap();
        });

        Mapper = MapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();

        services.AddInstance(Mapper);
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        // AutoMapper Configuration moved out of here.
    }
```